# Fetch values in DROPDOWN from MySQL table using Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a MySQL Database having region and country. Each Country is connected to a Region. For Example:

**Country--- Region**

Cambodia- South East Asia

Thailand - South East Asia

India -  Asia

Srilanka - Asia

Melbourne - Australia

I have a front end where I can select Region from a dropdown and I want related countries to show up in the next dropdown

My Current HTML Code is:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>Region:</label>
    <select name="region">
        <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
        <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
        <option value="Melbourne">Melbourne</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Country:</label>
    <select name="country">
        <option value="South East Asia">South East Asia</option>
        <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
        <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I want to have this option when I select a Region, only the countries listed under it should show up in the next dropdown. For example if I select South East Asia it should only show Cambodia and Thailand. If I select Asia, it should only show India and Sri Lanka.

Is there any way to do it using AJAX?

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried. There are many ways to do this with AJAX.

Comment: Try this. http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html